# How to check for conditions in a text file line that is deliminated by tabs in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

In VBA, how can I read a line in a text file and check for certain values? I have a text file that looks similar to this:

```
a     b     c     d     e     f     g [this line is not in the code]  
1[tab]2[tab]3[tab]4[tab]5[tab]6[tab]7
8[tab]9[tab]10[tab]11[tab]12[tab]13[tab]14
…
```

The numbers represent values associated with different parameters that are separated by tabs. Each row corresponds with a new set of data. So in the above example, 1 and 8 are the same parameter (in this case, "a") for two different experiments. I want my code to read each line and print the entire line into a new text document if b, c, d, and f equal certain values. I have the rest of the code figured out if someone could give me some advise regarding this.

```
Private Sub SingleRun_button_Click()

myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Delimiter = vbTab
Dim intDialogResult As Integer, _
    strPath, strLine, arrString() As String, _
    i, j, intCurrColumn, D, B, DischMod, T As Integer, _
    fso, ofile As Object

D = Me.D_CB.Value
B = Me.B_CB.Value
DischMod = Me.DischMod_CB.Value
T = Me.T_CB.Value

Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
Call Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Filters.Clear
Call Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Filters.Add("Text Files", "*.txt")
intDialogResult = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set ofile = fs.createtextfile(strPath)

Close #1
Open strPath For Input As #1
i = 1
While EOF(1) = False
    Line Input #1, strLine
    arrString = Split(strLine, vbTab)
    intCurrColumn = 1
    For j = LBound(arrString) To UBound(arrString)
    If arrString(j) <> vbTab Then
        'Code as described below
    End If
Next
i = i + 1
Wend
Close #1

Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please visit [ask] before posting questions to understand what is expected when asking questions on [so]. Can you show a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you are encountering?

Comment: @Lankymart I'm honestly not quite sure where to start since the data is deliminated by tabs. I can post the code, will edit my post and insert the entire code if that helps.

Comment: Appreciate the effort, but ideally a [mcve] that demonstrates the specific problem you are having works best. If the problem isn’t specific enough it just turns into a request code question which will be promptly flagged and closed.

Comment: `If arrString(j) <> vbTab Then` - when you use Split() the resulting array doesn't contain the string you split on (tab in this case) so you don't need this test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you.  Just read your input file line by line, `SPLI` it by the delimeter (TAB) and you can whatever you want with it.

```
Private Sub ReadCSV()

    Dim str As String
    Dim arr As Variant

        Open ("your_file_path") For Input As #1
            While Not EOF(1)
                Line Input #1, str
                arr = Split(str, vbTab)

                For a = 1 To UBound(arr)
                    Debug.Print arr(a)
                Next
            Wend
        Close #2

End Sub
```

Comment: @Kara Although you might get lucky with someone looking for easy rep. Case in point.

Answer (score 0):

Untested but here's a basic approach:

```
Sub tester()

    Dim myFile
    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()

    If myFile <> False Then
        FilterFile myFile, "C:\Data\filtered.txt", "b", "c", "d", "f"
    End If
End Sub



Sub FilterFile(sPathIn, sPathOut, valB, valC, valD, valF)

    Dim FSO As Object, fIn As Object, fOut As Object, arr As Variant, l

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Set fIn = FSO.OpenTextFile(sPathIn, 1) '1=ForReading
    Set fOut = FSO.OpenTextFile(sPathOut, 2) '2=ForWriting

    Do While Not fIn.AtEndOfStream

        l = fIn.ReadLine
        arr = Split(l, vbTab)

        'check this line for required criteria
        'arr is zero-based, so arr(0) = ColA, arr(1) = ColB, etc
        If arr(1) = valB And arr(2) = valC And arr(3) = valD And arr(5) = valF Then
            fOut.WriteLine l
        End If
    Loop

    fIn.Close
    fOut.Close
End Sub
```